# Reference-like introductory resources for molecular modelling in drug discovery?

Tags: molecular-modeling, drug-design

Reference-like introductory resources for molecular modelling in drug discovery?

Particularly I want to cover:

- Underlying chemical phenomena and methods
- Mathematical methods that have been demonstrated to be useful
- Some common practices in the field, such as 3D-QSAR

Answer (score 3):

I really loved these two books:

#### Graham L. Patrick. [An Introduction to Medicinal Chemistry](https://global.oup.com/uk/orc/chemistry/patrick6e/). Fifth Edition. Oxford University Press.

The structure of the book is the following:

- Part A contains six chapters that cover the structure
  and function of important drug targets, such as receptors, enzymes, and nucleic acids. Students with a
  strong background in biochemistry will already know
  this material, but may find these chapters a useful
  revision of the essential points.
- Part B covers pharmacodynamics in Chapters 7–10
  and pharmacokinetics in Chapter 11. Pharmacodynamics is the study of how drugs interact with their molecular targets and the consequences of those interactions. Pharmacokinetics relates to the issues involved in a drug reaching its target in the first place.
- Part C covers the general principles and strategies
  involved in discovering and designing new drugs and
  developing them for the marketplace.
- Part D looks at particular ‘tools of the trade’ which are
  invaluable in drug design, i.e. QSAR, combinatorial
  synthesis, and computer-aided design.
- Part E covers a selection of specific topics within
  medicinal chemistry—antibacterial, antiviral and
  anti cancer agents, cholinergics and anti-cholinesterases, adrenergics, opioid analgesics, and anti-ulcer agents. To some extent, those chapters reflect the changing emphasis in medicinal chemistry research.

#### Torsten Schwede and Manuel C Peitsch. [Computational Structural Biology: Methods and Applications](https://doi.org/10.1142/6659). Word Scientific.

The structure of the book is the following:

- Structure Prediction and Assessment Methods: Protein Fold Recognition and Threading. Assessment of Protein Structure Predictions.
- From Structure to Function to Design: Evolution of Protein Folds. Atomistic Simulations of Reactions and Transition States Protein-Protein Interactions and Aggregation Processes.
- Drug Discovery and Pharmacology: Molecular Dynamics-Based Free Energy Simulations. Structure-Based Computational Approaches to Drug Metabolism.
- New Frontiers in Experimental Methods: New Frontiers in X-Ray Crystallography. New Frontiers in Characterizing Structure and Dynamics by NMR.
- Selected Topics: Docking for Neglected Diseases as Community Efforts. Protein Structure Databases. Molecular Graphics in Structural Biology.